# SVN: When does Tree Conflict - "local delete, incoming edit upon update" happens?

Tags: php, svn, tortoisesvn, directory, conflict

**What I did :**

1. Performed `svn up`
2. Renamed a folder from `foo` to `bar`
3. Again performed `svn up` and got the conflict : `local delete, incoming edit upon update`

**But why ?**

- I did `svn log -v` and found no commit post `step 1`
- So, in that case svn should understand that I am renaming `foo` to `bar`
- Why to raise a conflict if no one else has made changes to `foo` ?

Please explain how does svn looks at this situation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cause: SVN does not know that you renamed the directory. In the meanwhile someone edited files in the directory and SVN is trying to find it in order to update. To rename the directory properly: rename it back to the old name locally and then run `svn rename` command (do `svn rename --help` for more info). You do not have to commit right away.

Note that `svn log` prints out the log starting with **BASE** revision - i.e. the last updated revision of your working copy, so you need to do `svn log foo@HEAD` to really see if anybody changed it.

Answer (score -1):

To rename a directory you have to use the svn rename command. 
If you want to recover your directory : delete it (right click -> delete) and do an svn up

Comment: This is not my question - How to rename in svn. My question is when and why is this conflict raised ?